# Where in the spec file can I put instructions to install/move around files when I run the install command?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Where in the spec file can I put instructions to install/move around files when I run the install command?

```
rpm -ivh myrpm-1.0-12.rpm
```

In my RPM I have a tar ball filled with files (php files) I want to place them onto my servers in a set directory.

I run.

```
rpmbuild -ba
```

This executes the commands below, that I don't want to execute at this time.

```
%install
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/mypath/here
cp -r . $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/mypath/here
```

I want these commands to be executed by the time of the install by the end user

```
rpm -ivh myrpm-1.0-12.rpm
```

In the RPM documentation it says that on of the steps of installing an RPM is...
"Unpacking files from the package and putting them in the proper place:"

This is the step most people think of when they think about installing software. Each package file contains a list of files that are to be installed, as well as their destination on your system. In addition, many other file attributes, such as permissions and ownerships, are set correctly by RPM.

I don't know where to put these commands.

I've also tried putting the commands in `%build` and it acts that same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPM build time is the exact time to extract these files.

The original tar ball is supposed to be part of the "source RPM file", and the "binary RPM file" (bad wording; should maybe be better "install RPM file" in this case) is supposed to hold the exact layout of the target file system the RPM is responsible for.

This layout is defined in the `%install` section. Usually, you have the sequence `%prep`, `%build` and `%install`. `%prep` unpacks your sources into the working directory, `%build` builds them adnd `%install` moves the stoff to the "build root" which defines the files supposed to be there. If you don't have anything to build, as in your case, you omit `%build` and maybe just unpack in the `%install` section.

This is as well the only way the RPM system can know the names of the files so you can query their package with `rpm -qf $FILENAME`. (except with ghost files, but that's not very elegant).

You can add a `%post` scriptlet which unpacks a tarball at install time, but, as said, that would be far from elegant.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. So if I have a folder that wanted to be unpacked say, mydir/index.php And I want the exact layout of the file to be /usr/local/mypath/here/mydir/index.php on the machine, where do I specify that? You said, [the .rpm file] is supposed to hold the exact layout of the target file system the RPM is responsible for. Where do I specify that layout?

Comment: @Eddie In the `%install` section. That's what the `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` part is all about. You create the **exact** layout you want on the target system under the `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` prefix and then `rpmbuild` packages everything under that directory up as your package.

Comment: @EtanReisner 
So the %install runs when I run 'rpm -ivh myrpm...' ?
I put an echo statement in and I didn't see it? I did see it when I built the rpm (rpmbuild -ba myrpm....)

Comment: @Eddie No. `%install` runs when you *build* the package. `%pre` and `%post` run when you install the RPM. You *don't* want to extract anything then though. That's not how you package things. Like I said you set up **exactly** the directory structure you want the **target** system to have under `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` during `%install` and then `rpmbuild` packages all those files up in the rpm package and extracts those to the right locations when it is installed. Also you generally don't want to use `rpm -i` using `rpm -U` is much better behaved in general.